# cakephp - building a query with a multi-word search string, searching multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a model 'Mix' which has the fields (which I'd like to be searchable) 'name' 'description' and 'tag_words', as well as a boolean field 'published'. Users should be able to enter a multi-word search term and get results back for any of their words appearing in any of the searchable fields providing the 'published' field is set to 1

So far with the help of google and reading around on here I've got:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $conditions = array();
    $search_terms = explode(' ', $this->request->data['Mix']['search']);
    foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
        $conditions[] = array('Mix.name Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%');
        $conditions[] = array('Mix.description Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%');
        $conditions[] = array('Mix.tag_words Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%');
    }
    $searchResults = $this->paginate('Mix', array('conditions' => array('Mix.published'=>1, 'AND'=>array('OR' => $conditions))));
}
```

But since it returns nothing but loads of errors I can guess it's totally wrong. I've very confused, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: where did you wrote above code (in model or controller) & what error you got?

Comment: I put the code in the controller, I've posted the error in the comments to the answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the `AND` index, it is already implied:-

```
$searchResults = $this->paginate('Mix', array('conditions' => array('Mix.published'=>1, 'OR' => $conditions)));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. But when I try that I'm getting the error: SQL Query: SELECT `Mix`.`id`, `Mix`.`created_by`, `Mix`.`name`, `Mix`.`description`, `Mix`.`published`, `Mix`.`temporary`, `Mix`.`bgimage`, `Mix`.`bgcolor`, `Mix`.`tag_words`, `Mix`.`columns`, `Mix`.`rows`, `Mix`.`date_added`, `Mix`.`tile` FROM `homestartpage`.`mixes` AS `Mix` WHERE `conditions` IN (1, Array) LIMIT 20

Comment: oops, sorry, the error is:  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conditions' in 'where clause' then there is the query I posted above

Comment: Ah, ok I was being stupid. I copied my code from elsewhere and didn't realise I needed to add the pagination to the controller. Got it sorted now. Sorry :(